# Remove space inside fields to match in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query

```
   SELECT 
     course_locations.id as locId,
     courses.arrangements as arrangementStatus
   FROM course_locations
     LEFT JOIN courses ON course_locations.course_id = courses.id
     LEFT JOIN providers ON course_locations.provider_id = providers.id
     LEFT JOIN product_types ON product_types.id = courses.product_type_id
   WHERE 
     courses.arrangements ='0'
     AND providers.activated = 1
     AND course_locations.published_status ='1'
     AND course_locations.postcode IN(
                      SELECT 
                       DISTINCT(Postcode) as post 
                      FROM coordinaten 
                      WHERE FK_Provincie ='10' 
                       AND Latitude IS NOT NULL 
                       AND Longitude IS NOT NULL)
```

The issue I am facing is that the sub query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(Postcode) as post 
    FROM coordinaten 
    WHERE FK_Provincie ='10' 
    AND Latitude IS NOT NULL 
    AND Longitude IS NOT NULL
```

provides me result something like this `'2222AD','1111AE','2542DR'`.
But the course_locations.postcode has the values something like this `'2222 AD','1111 AE','2542 DR'`.
It has space in-between number and alphabets, so when I query I am not able to get the specified result.
Is there any way to get the match if the field has space or also if it has no space in between.
I am not able to use like also as the values comes as comma seperated from the sub-query.
Please let me know if someone has any idea of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string **from_str**
>   replaced by the string **to_str**. REPLACE() performs a *case-sensitive*
>   match when searching for from_str.

Your sub-query would look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(REPLACE(Postcode, ' ', '')) as post                                                                          FROM coordinaten
WHERE FK_Provincie ='10'
AND Latitude IS NOT NULL
AND Longitude IS NOT NULL
```

**Sample Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e5b/2

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to clean up the data, so the postcode format is consistent.

```
UPDATE [sometable] SET postcode=REPLACE(postcode,' ','');
```

removes spaces from postcode.

Failing this option, you could do this

```
... WHERE REPLACE(table_A.postcode,' ','') = REPLACE(table_B.postcode,' ','')
```

But this is less efficient, as the replacement have to be done on each compare, and it breaks indexes.

You naturally only have to do the replace on the tables which might have spaces in the postcode.